# What are these semi transparent pill-shaped things in the Mediterranean Sea?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, invertebrates

I was swimming with gopro in Sardinia, Le Bombarde beach in early November and today was reviewing footage - I noticed that water is full of semitransparent whitish "pills", see pictures below.
Any idea what that is, is it seasonal, has any implications to people taking a swim?
Jellyfish nearby should give approx idea of the size, seems something like 1-2cm long.

[image: strange things in the sea]
[image: strange things in the sea]

Answer (score 8):

Quick guess based on your low-quality photo:

Reminds me of a [**pyrosome**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosome), a tube/rod-shaped, free floating colonial [tunicate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunicate).

According to [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304460286_Pyrosoma_atlanticum_in_the_Mediterranean_Sea_abundance_and_spatial_distribution_from_extensive_planktonic_and_benthic_surveys_BEST_POSTER_AWARD), [*Pyrosoma atlanticum*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrosoma_atlanticum) is the only species found in the Mediterranean.

[image]

<sup>Image Credit: [amutti](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/98173866); Source: [inatrualist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/51108-Pyrosoma-atlanticum/browse_photos)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Image Credit: [Megan Mariposa](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/151163114); Source: [inatrualist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/51108-Pyrosoma-atlanticum/browse_photos)</sup>

See [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/51108-Pyrosoma-atlanticum/browse_photos),[National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/pyrosome-fire-body-bloom-eastern-pacific-warm-water) and [Project Noah](https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/14912463) for images of similar body shapes.

Comment: Unbelievable! Can you earn the ID badge twice?

Comment: @anongoodnurse :p. thanks! I should go earn it on Outdoors.SE ha! ;)